# Iphone Save data and go back to the previous view controller

Tags: iphone, ios5, storyboard

I have a Table View Controller which I have designed using storyboards. This has an Add button on the navigation bar and I created all this using storyboards. On Add button clicked I have a view controller view to add data and this has a save button on the navigation bar. On Save button Clicked I want the user to save data and return to the TableViewController. All the design was done using storyboards. On Save button clicked I am calling the IBAction save method.  I am able to save data but how do I go back to the previous TableViewController programmatically.

thanks
prerna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your IBAction save method, call:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```